# Controlled access to private member

Tags: c++

I have a class that contains a private std::vector and a flag. Every time an Object inside the vector is modified I want to set that flag.

This is what I came up with..

```
struct Object
{
    float f;
    int i;
}

class SomeClass
{
private:
    std::vector<Object> Data;
    bool Updated;

public:
    inline const std::vector<Object>& ReadData const
    {
        return Data;
    }
    inline std::vector<Object>& WriteData
    {
        Updated = false;
        return Data;
    }
}
```

This design is the safest I could come up with. The only issue with this is the fact I can bypass this safety mechanism when I'm using `Data` inside `SomeClass`.

So, even though I don't have lots of methods in `SomeClass` that operate on `Data`, could you suggest me a better design to achieve this? (Tracking every change to `Data` by setting `Updated` accordingly)

Comment: Move and copy constructor overload?

Comment: if you return a non-const ref to `Data` the caller can modify `Data` as much as they like without you noticing it

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number yes! it is fine as long as `Updated` is set to `false`

Comment: whats the use of the flag? Once it is `false` you can never safely set it back to `true`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number `SomeClass` has an Update method that does some stuff and sets `Updated` to true.  `Data` is used inside a couple of big functions, and first thing they do is to check `Updated` and call `Update` when it's false.  Again this is just the best I could come up with and I always feel naked when showing my ideas to the experts here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution fails to achieve what you want.

> SomeClass has an Update method that does some stuff and sets Updated to true. Data is used inside a couple of big functions, and first thing they do is to check Updated and call Update when it's false. Again this is just the best I could come up with and I always feel naked when showing my ideas to the experts here

I guess what you had in mind was something like this:

```
SomeClass sc;
auto& data = sc.WriteData(); 
sc.Update();                     // checks if Updated is set to false
                                 // if necessary Updates the data and
                                 // resets Updated to true
sc.do_some_thing_with_data();    // this can use Data as is because Updated is true
```

But your "encapsulation" does not prevent a user to do this:

```
SomeClass sc;
auto& data = sc.WriteData();  // Updated = false
sc.Update();                  // Updated = true

data[0] = 42;                 // modify Data

sc.do_some_thing_with_data(); // assumes data has not been modified
```

I suppose you actually want to call `Update` inside `do_some_thing_with_data`, however that does not change the problem:

```
auto& data = sc.WriteData();  // Updated = false

sc.do_some_thing_with_data(); // checks Updated, updates the data
                              // and resets Updated = true
                              // assumes data is updated -> OK
data[0] = 42;

sc.do_some_thing_with_data(); // checks Updated,
                              // does not update data because Updated is still true
                              // assumes data is updated -> WRONG
```

Once you returned a non-const reference you are no longer in control of modifiying the member. Your flag does not provide the "security" you expect. Returning a non-const reference is not encapsulation!

You can either not return a non-const reference, or don't pretend to encapsulate data when you don't encapusalte data (ie make the member `public`). If you want to be in control of modifications to data then do something along the line of:

```
class SomeClass
{
private:
    std::vector<Object> Data;
    bool Updated;

public:
    const std::vector<Object>& ReadData const
    {
        return Data;
    }
    void WriteData(const Object& obj,size_t index)
    {
        Data[index] = obj;
        Updated = false;
    }
    void WriteF(float f,size_t index){
        Data[index].f = f;
        Updated = false;
    }
    void WriteI(int i,size_t index){
        Data[index].i = i;
        Updated = false;
    }
}
```

And if you are worried about `SomeClass` being able to modify `Data` by bypassing the setters then thats because you want `SomeClass` do too much. Do other stuff in a different class:

```
 struct SomeOtherClass {
       SomeClass sc;
 };
```

Now `SomeOtherClass` can only modify `Data` in a controlled way.

PS: You seem to got confused by encapsulation vs no encapsulation. To reiterate: Returning a non-const reference is not encapsulation. If you want to encapsulate `Data` then make it `private` and do not provide direct access to it. The class that is in charge of encapsulating data has direct access to it. Other classes don't.

Comment: You got a valid point there, but I still can't see another solution to this... To avoid situations as the one you mentioned I created a `DataUpdater` class that has a pointer to `Data` and checks the `Update` flag in the constructor and calls `Update()` in his destructor, and I Instantiate it at the begin of each one of those big functions that write to `Data`. I really can't think of another solution that lets me access `Data` in those functions and keep track of the changes

Comment: @AathakA the solution is to either not use encapsulation, or use proper encapsulation, ie instead of handing a non-const reference to the caller you can provide a method `set_element_at( Object o, size_t index);` then the caller can modify an element and your class can know when such a modification happens. You want encapsulation so use it. Your current solution is no encapsulation

Comment: @AathakA see update

Answer (score 1):

> The only issue with this is the fact I can bypass this safety mechanism when I'm using Data inside SomeClass.

Sooooo encapsulate what you want to encapsulate, not something else. You could put your whole program in the class, and argue it would have access then to all private members. So don't, encapsulate it.

```
class Data {
   std::vector<Object> data;
   bool updated;
public:
   std::vector<Object>& read() const {
       return data;
   }
   std::vector<Object>& write() {
        updated = false;
        return Data;
   }
};


class SomeClass {
    Data data;
public:
    const std::vector<Object>& readData() const {
        return data.read();
    }
    std::vector<Object>& writeData() {
        return data.write();
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks! Are there any ways that could 'break' that safety there? i.e. should I delete/make protected constructor/move/assignment constructor etc?